# Magento 2: How to disable the sidebar for certain category?

Tags: magento-2.1, filter, admin-panel, category-products, sidebar

I have a category structure like this:

[image: magento 2 category structure]

Every time I go to products page after selecting one of the categories in frontend there's sidebar for filtering product, I want to disable it only if I click the descendant of category name **Create**, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Select category, display settings change to one column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change on the design tab, setting the layout to **1 column** and check the **Apply Design to Products**, like that:

[image: Magento 2 Categories layout]

Answer (score 0):

> My Comment at question:    Select category, display settings change to
>   one column – Teja bhagavan Kollepara 1 hour ago

1. You can get that by changing the layout in the design tab
2. Set the layout to 1 column
3. Check the Apply Design to Products.